# Disable datatips in Atom Text Editor

Tags: reactjs, react-native, atom-editor

Does anyone know how to disable "datatips" in the Atom IDE?

It's been a real pain editing Stylesheets for my react native project.

[image: Screenshot of the DataTips popup]

Whenever I click on a line in order to edit it, the "datatips" panel will pop up, making it very hard to type.

Comment: Probably this helps https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/16320

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @divyanshu-maithani

Inspected the element like suggested (View -> Developer -> Toggle Developer Tools) in the git post and then added the following to Atom -> StyleSheet

```
.datatip-marked-container {
    display: none;
}
```